# Consuming error logs with Twilio API

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I have developed an application that sends thousands of SMS using Twilio Notify Service.

```
const bindings = phoneNumbers.map(number =>
  this.createBinding('sms', number)
);
await this.notifyService.notifications.create({
  toBinding: bindings,
  body
});
```

The code above doesn't give me a feedback of whether the messages were received or not, but as I can see in Twilio dashboard, some messages fail with error codes 30005, 30003, 30006 and 52001.

I'd like to consume all those error logs and unsubscribe the numbers with error codes. I'm thinking of creating a job that runs every night to do that.

I've tried to list all the alerts:

```
client.monitor.alerts.each(alert => {
  console.log(alert.errorCode);
});
```

But it seems to fetch only some alerts with error code 52001.

How can I consume all the errors with Twilio API? Is there any other way to be notified of those errors?